# Studying the following Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, cauchy-problem

I have the following Cauchy problem:

$$ y' = y^2 - (\arctan{x})^2$$
$$ y(1) = 0 $$

I want to draw a the plot of the solution.

This is what I have so far:

$f(x,y) = y^2 - (\arctan{x})^2 $ is $C^\infty$ so I have Lipschizianity, therefore  existence and uniqueness of local solution. It can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ as a global solution.

I also know that the function is increasing when: 
$$ \vert{y}\vert > \vert\arctan{x}\vert $$

But I am struggling to see the big picture here, how do I go on?

Comment: The big picture can be seen perfectly by sketching the slope field.

Comment: Did you try to find online resources to get an idea of what a solution could look like? Geogebra has a nice tool https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc, also looking good is https://bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/slopefields.html